# How to get data from fs.readFile in vuejs3

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack

I'm running this script

```
//package.js
"scripts": {
  "serve": "node readFile.js & vue-cli-service serve"
},

//readFile.js
const data = fs.readFileSync('path/file', 'utf-8')
```

How do I get the "data" available in vue?

Comment: What is the content/data format of the file? json ? binary? text?

Comment: format is .json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to make this data available in your Vue app is to use the `define` plugin in Webpack:

```js
// vue.config.js
const my_data = require('./path/file.json');
module.exports =
{
  chainWebpack: config =>
  {
    config.plugin('define').tap(args =>
    {
      args[0]['process.env'].MY_JSON_DATA = JSON.stringify(my_data);
      return args;
    });
  }
}
```

Then you can access your data as `process.env.MY_JSON_DATA`